# How I solve file not found problem in python script?

Tags: python, tkinter, location, tkinter.iconbitmap

I had made a program where I require files from that directory where the python file is located. The files are located in the same folder where the python file located.

I can't write the full path of the file in the python script
I used the **./** method in the script but it gives error

Please help me to solve the problem

here is my code

'''

#code

```
root=Tk()
root.title("SOHAM YOUTUBE VIDEO DOWNLOADER")
root["bg"]='#1F1F1F'
root.iconbitmap("./img/youtube_(1).ico")
root.geometry("900x680")

file =PhotoImage(file="./img/youtube-icon.png")
headingIcon=Label(root, image=file)
headingIcon.pack(side=TOP, pady=3)
```

'''

My folder location

[image: here img is my required folder in YOUTUBE_VEDIO_DOWNLOADER.py which is my python file]

Here **img** is my required folder in **YOUTUBE_VIDEO_DOWNLOADER.py** which is my python file

My script error is given below

```
y"python "e:/python projects/YOUTUBE VIDEO DOWNLOADER/YOUTUBE_VIDEO_DOWNLOADER.py
Traceback (most recent call last):*emphasized text*
  File "e:\python projects\YOUTUBE VIDEO DOWNLOADER\YOUTUBE_VIDEO_DOWNLOADER.py", line 215, in <module>
    root.iconbitmap("./img/youtube_(1).ico")
  File "C:\Users\soham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2073, in wm_iconbitmap
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "./img/youtube_(1).ico" not defined
```

Comment: Please don't use images to describe anything. In this case use text to describe your folder hierarchy.

Comment: The error means that the ico file cannot be found.

Comment: I had use .ico file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One trick I use to account for this problem, is to use the `__file__` variable (which holds the path of the scripts file) as my reference path and then write the path to the file I want.

If your directory looks like this:

```
my_dir
|> my_script.py
|> img/
   |> my_img.png
```

Then `__file__` will be equal to `C:\\...\my_dir\my_script.py`.

And your image will be `os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'img', 'my_img.png')`

Comment: Sir I had tried it but it not working
icopath = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), 'img', 'youtube_(1)')
root.iconbitmap(icopath)

Comment: Error
$ python "e:/python projects/YOUTUBE VIDEO DOWNLOADER/YOUTUBE_VIDEO_DOWNLOADER.py"
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "e:\python projects\YOUTUBE VIDEO DOWNLOADER\YOUTUBE_VIDEO_DOWNLOADER.py", line 221, in <module>
    root.iconbitmap(icopath)
  File "C:\Users\soham\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 2073, in wm_iconbitmap
    return self.tk.call('wm', 'iconbitmap', self._w, bitmap)
_tkinter.TclError: bitmap "e:\python projects\YOUTUBE VIDEO DOWNLOADER\img\youtube_(1)" not defined

Comment: I think you forgot the `.ico` in the image name

Comment: no sir I had wrote .ico file
and it start working when I gave the full path of the file
but I require to give it a short path like "./img/youtube_(1).ico"

Comment: I think you can print the full path you made and the path that uses `__file__`. Compare them and adjust the code accordingly.

Comment: when I print the path it gives "e:\python projects\YOUTUBE VIDEO DOWNLOADER\YOUTUBE_VIDEO_DOWNLOADER.py"

Comment: Sir I have to replace "YOUTUBE_VIDEO_DOWNLOADER.py" to "img\youtube_(1)"

Comment: Sir I had tried  a code "root.iconbitmap(__file__+"/../img/youtube_(1).ico")"
 and it worked

Comment: Thank you Sir, for help me and spend your precious time